# Will the absolute logarithm always produce the correct real result if one exists?

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation, absolute-value

I'm a computer scientist, so my math skills are a bit rudimentary. The application I'm writing is more or less about solving equations. I'm only interested in real number solutions, so imaginary numbers are forbidden. In this particular example, the equation has the form $$a = b^{x}$$
where $a$ and $b$ are given. What I'm looking for is a **real** solution for $x$ if it exists and if it doesn't I want to know that it doesn't.

What I can't do is calculating $$x = \frac{log(a)}{log(b)}$$ and check if it's real, because I'm restricted to real arithmetic functions. However I discovered, that calculating the "absolute log" $$x' = \frac{log(|a|)}{log(|b|)}$$ seems to produce the correct solution if a real solution exists and if it doesn't then $$-a= b^{x'}$$ will hold true. However, I have no proof of this.

So my question is: Does the "absolute log" function have the property that I described earlier? And if it does, how can I prove it?

Comment: If $a<0$ and $b>0$ then your "absolute log" still gives a real value $x^\prime$, even though the equation has no real solutions. For example, in the equation $-4=2^x$, we clearly have no real solution, but your absolute log would give a value of $x^\prime=2$.

Comment: Correct, that's the second property I described. Because no real solution exists, $-(-4) = 4 = 2^2$ holds true.

Comment: Ah. I see. I missed the minus sign in the second property.

Answer (score 0):

Your $x'$ solves the equation $|a| = |b|^x$. Note that you can face a multitude of problems if you assume that the numbers a and b can be nonpositive.

- If $b = 0$, the equation only has a solution if $a \in \{0, 1\}$. For $a = 0$ every $x > 0$ solves the equation, while for $a = 1$ the only solution is $x = 0$ (c.f. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Powers_of_zero)).
- If $b > 0$ and $a \le 0$, the equation does not have a solution at all.
- If $b < 0$, the term $b^x$ is in general not well-defined for all real numbers $x$ (c.f. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Real_exponents_with_negative_bases))

Comment: $b = 0$ is an interesting corner case, I will check that. Your second case is equivalent to the "no real solution" case and $-a=b^{x'}$ applies. For the third case, it's enough if it's well-defined for say whole numbers. If $a = 4$ and $b=-2$ then $x' = 2$ which is what I would expect.

Comment: The last case is again more complicated. For example if $b = -1$ and $a = 1$, every even integer solves the equation, while for $a = -1$ every odd integer solves the equation.

Comment: One correct solution is enough for me. However you raise a valid point, $log(1) = 0$ leads to some undesired effects.